# Upgrading Printer Server 2016 to 2019

Tags: print-server

I am planning to upgrade our print server configured on Windows Server 2016 to 2019. I am planning to proceed with in-place upgrade. Have you tried in-place upgrade of printer server from 2016 to 2019 ? Any issues noticed during/after the upgrade ?

Answer (score 2):

In place upgrade from 2016 to 2019 is a supported path.

Make sure to have a good backup before in case it go bad, and to migrate a printserver I would recommand before the in place upgrade to export your print queues. It's easier to import to another server if the inplace upgrade fail. Per printbrm or via the GUI;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes i am aware it is supported path. I was interested to find out if someone gone through this in-place upgrade path for Print Server and found any issues during/after the upgrade.